# CameraXLivePreview: Can not create image processor: Object Detection

Tags: java, android, google-mlkit

I'm creating an app using a MLkit and finally I made it. But it's not working and keep send me a errors I can't understand why error keep occurs.. here is my code and error pls help me

I just copied from MLKit example quick start sample for only using a pose
detector and it says " Invalid model name" .. I don't know why it does saying can you guys help me??

```
/*
 * Copyright 2020 Google LLC. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example.pose;

import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build.VERSION;
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Size;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import androidx.camera.core.CameraInfoUnavailableException;
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector;
import androidx.camera.core.Preview;
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider;
import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName;
import com.google.mlkit.common.MlKitException;
import com.google.mlkit.common.model.LocalModel;
import com.example.pose.CameraXViewModel;
import com.example.pose.GraphicOverlay;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.demo.R;
import com.example.pose.VisionImageProcessor;
import com.example.pose.posedetector.PoseDetectorProcessor;
import com.example.pose.preference.PreferenceUtils;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.pose.PoseDetectorOptions;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/** Live preview demo app for ML Kit APIs using CameraX. */
@KeepName
@RequiresApi(VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public final class CameraXLivePreviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback,
        OnItemSelectedListener,
        CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    private static final String TAG = "CameraXLivePreview";
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUESTS = 1;

    private static final String OBJECT_DETECTION = "Object Detection";

    private static final String POSE_DETECTION = "Pose Detection";

    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_MODEL = "selected_model";
    private static final String STATE_LENS_FACING = "lens_facing";

    private PreviewView previewView;
    private GraphicOverlay graphicOverlay;

    @Nullable private ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider;
    @Nullable private Preview previewUseCase;
    @Nullable private ImageAnalysis analysisUseCase;
    @Nullable private VisionImageProcessor imageProcessor;
    private boolean needUpdateGraphicOverlayImageSourceInfo;

    private String selectedModel = OBJECT_DETECTION;
    private int lensFacing = CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK;
    private CameraSelector cameraSelector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

        if (VERSION.SDK_INT < VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "CameraX is only supported on SDK version >=21. Current SDK version is "
                            + VERSION.SDK_INT,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            return;
        }

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            selectedModel = savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_SELECTED_MODEL, OBJECT_DETECTION);
            lensFacing = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LENS_FACING, CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK);
        }
        cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(lensFacing).build();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vision_camerax_live_preview);
        previewView = findViewById(R.id.preview_view);
        if (previewView == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "previewView is null");
        }
        graphicOverlay = findViewById(R.id.graphic_overlay);
        if (graphicOverlay == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "graphicOverlay is null");
        }


        ToggleButton facingSwitch = findViewById(R.id.facing_switch);
        facingSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        new ViewModelProvider(this, AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(getApplication()))
                .get(CameraXViewModel.class)
                .getProcessCameraProvider()
                .observe(
                        this,
                        provider -> {
                            cameraProvider = provider;
                            if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                                bindAllCameraUseCases();
                            }
                        });


        if (!allPermissionsGranted()) {
            getRuntimePermissions();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
        bundle.putString(STATE_SELECTED_MODEL, selectedModel);
        bundle.putInt(STATE_LENS_FACING, lensFacing);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
        selectedModel = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        Log.d(TAG, "Selected model: " + selectedModel);
        bindAnalysisUseCase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Set facing");
        if (cameraProvider == null) {
            return;
        }

        int newLensFacing =
                lensFacing == CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT
                        ? CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK
                        : CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT;
        CameraSelector newCameraSelector =
                new CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(newLensFacing).build();
        try {
            if (cameraProvider.hasCamera(newCameraSelector)) {
                lensFacing = newLensFacing;
                cameraSelector = newCameraSelector;
                bindAllCameraUseCases();
                return;
            }
        } catch (CameraInfoUnavailableException e) {
            // Falls through
        }
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "This device does not have lens with facing: " + newLensFacing,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        bindAllCameraUseCases();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (imageProcessor != null) {
            imageProcessor.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (imageProcessor != null) {
            imageProcessor.stop();
        }
    }

    private void bindAllCameraUseCases() {
        if (cameraProvider != null) {
            // As required by CameraX API, unbinds all use cases before trying to re-bind any of them.
            cameraProvider.unbindAll();
            bindPreviewUseCase();
            bindAnalysisUseCase();
        }
    }

    private void bindPreviewUseCase() {
        if (!PreferenceUtils.isCameraLiveViewportEnabled(this)) {
            return;
        }
        if (cameraProvider == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (previewUseCase != null) {
            cameraProvider.unbind(previewUseCase);
        }

        previewUseCase = new Preview.Builder().build();
        previewUseCase.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.createSurfaceProvider());
        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(/* lifecycleOwner= */ this, cameraSelector, previewUseCase);
    }

    private void bindAnalysisUseCase() {
        if (cameraProvider == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (analysisUseCase != null) {
            cameraProvider.unbind(analysisUseCase);
        }
        if (imageProcessor != null) {
            imageProcessor.stop();
        }

        try {
            switch (selectedModel) {
                case POSE_DETECTION:
                    PoseDetectorOptions poseDetectorOptions =
                            PreferenceUtils.getPoseDetectorOptionsForLivePreview(this);
                    boolean shouldShowInFrameLikelihood =
                            PreferenceUtils.shouldShowPoseDetectionInFrameLikelihoodLivePreview(this);
                    imageProcessor =
                            new PoseDetectorProcessor(this, poseDetectorOptions, shouldShowInFrameLikelihood);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid model name");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can not create image processor: " + selectedModel, e);
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Can not create image processor: " + e.getLocalizedMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            return;
        }

        ImageAnalysis.Builder builder = new ImageAnalysis.Builder();
        Size targetAnalysisSize = PreferenceUtils.getCameraXTargetAnalysisSize(this);
        if (targetAnalysisSize != null) {
            builder.setTargetResolution(targetAnalysisSize);
        }
        analysisUseCase = builder.build();

        needUpdateGraphicOverlayImageSourceInfo = true;
        analysisUseCase.setAnalyzer(
                // imageProcessor.processImageProxy will use another thread to run the detection underneath,
                // thus we can just runs the analyzer itself on main thread.
                ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
                imageProxy -> {
                    if (needUpdateGraphicOverlayImageSourceInfo) {
                        boolean isImageFlipped = lensFacing == CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT;
                        int rotationDegrees = imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees();
                        if (rotationDegrees == 0 || rotationDegrees == 180) {
                            graphicOverlay.setImageSourceInfo(
                                    imageProxy.getWidth(), imageProxy.getHeight(), isImageFlipped);
                        } else {
                            graphicOverlay.setImageSourceInfo(
                                    imageProxy.getHeight(), imageProxy.getWidth(), isImageFlipped);
                        }
                        needUpdateGraphicOverlayImageSourceInfo = false;
                    }
                    try {
                        imageProcessor.processImageProxy(imageProxy, graphicOverlay);
                    } catch (MlKitException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to process image. Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(/* lifecycleOwner= */ this, cameraSelector, analysisUseCase);
    }

    private String[] getRequiredPermissions() {
        try {
            PackageInfo info =
                    this.getPackageManager()
                            .getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
            String[] ps = info.requestedPermissions;
            if (ps != null && ps.length > 0) {
                return ps;
            } else {
                return new String[0];
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new String[0];
        }
    }

    private boolean allPermissionsGranted() {
        for (String permission : getRequiredPermissions()) {
            if (!isPermissionGranted(this, permission)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void getRuntimePermissions() {
        List<String> allNeededPermissions = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String permission : getRequiredPermissions()) {
            if (!isPermissionGranted(this, permission)) {
                allNeededPermissions.add(permission);
            }
        }

        if (!allNeededPermissions.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this, allNeededPermissions.toArray(new String[0]), PERMISSION_REQUESTS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
            int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Permission granted!");
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            bindAllCameraUseCases();
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    private static boolean isPermissionGranted(Context context, String permission) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Permission granted: " + permission);
            return true;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Permission NOT granted: " + permission);
        return false;
    }
}








    E/CameraXLivePreview: Can not create image processor: Object Detection
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid model name
        at com.example.pose.CameraXLivePreviewActivity.bindAnalysisUseCase(CameraXLivePreviewActivity.java:271)
        at com.example.pose.CameraXLivePreviewActivity.bindAllCameraUseCases(CameraXLivePreviewActivity.java:229)
        at com.example.pose.CameraXLivePreviewActivity.onCheckedChanged(CameraXLivePreviewActivity.java:187)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:218)
        at android.widget.ToggleButton.setChecked(ToggleButton.java:81)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:137)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:142)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: In `bindAnalysisUseCase` the code only supports `POSE_DETECTION` model and it looks like you default to `OBJECT_DETECTION` .  (I probaly would add the `selectedModel` string to the `IllegalStateException` message such as `"Invalid model name: "+selectedModel`.

Answer (score 1):

Please change this line to let the feature selector to select Pose detection
"private String selectedModel = OBJECT_DETECTION;"
to
"private String selectedModel = POSE_DETECTION;"